# Retorno xml com 406, Net Core 2.2, com FormatFilter?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core

Estou tentando fazer um retorno no meu `Controller` com `FormatFilter` `.xml`, mas recebo o ***406***.

Controller:

```
[HttpGet("xml/loja/{id}/{format}"), FormatFilter]
[Produces("application/xml")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult<filterResultSet>> GetXmlLoja(
    [FromHeader] Guid userId, 
    [FromHeader] string fileName, 
    Guid id
) 
{ 
    //FormatFilterAttribute format = FormatFilterAttribute.GetCustomAttribute(XmlDocument)
    //if (!_mapaRelatorioBO.Exists(id).Result) return NotFound(new { message = "MapaRelatorio não existente!" });
    //if (userId == null) return BadRequest(new { message = "Usuário não informado!" });
    return await _mapaRelatorioBO.GetXmlLoja(id, fileName);
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddMvcCore(options =>
{
    options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat
        ("xml", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/xml"));
    options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat
        ("config", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/xml"));
    options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat
        ("js", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
})
.AddFormatterMappings();

services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
});
```

Retorno

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O formato do envio é: `filterResultSet filter = new filterResultSet();`

```
namespace GI.NET.Insights.Dominio.Xml
{
    public class EstruturaLojaXml
    {


    }


    // NOTE: Generated code may require at least .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET Core/Standard 2.0.
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class filterResultSet
    {

        private filterResultSetFilterResult filterResultField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public filterResultSetFilterResult filterResult
        {
            get
            {
                return this.filterResultField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.filterResultField = value;
            }
        }
    } ...
```

pelo resultado que deveria ser sucesso o Swagger me mostra assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como você está enviando?

Comment: Coloquei na pergunta. :)

Comment: Me parece que a sua requisição não aceita receber um xml como resposta

Comment: Example Value é o exemplo que deve ser enviado, se está enviando esse xml?

Comment: No swagger, depois de clicar no `Try out` logo abaixo do botão execute, à direita, tem um select "Response content type", tentou mudar para "application/xml"?

Comment: é tem vários aspectos igual @LeandroAngelo citou para que tudo isso funciona...

Comment: @LeandroAngelo ele já mudou, quando executo o projeto. Coloquei a imagem dele completa.

Comment: @novic a classe EstruturaLojaXml monta o objeto XML completo, conforme foi gerado pelo próprio visual studio. a partir do objeto filterResult. Ele é muito grande, por isso não coloquei todo.

Comment: método get? são bastante problemas que eu já encontrei, o que você quer fazer basicamente?

Comment: Uma outra aplicação vai chamar a minha, e tenho que retornar um xml pra ela. Praticamente isso.

Comment: Quando faço a chamada da minha aplicação, ele lê ela toda. mas, no retorno da 406. Algo de Header. Até achei uma possível solução, mas só funciona para o core >3.0 
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: comoe está chamando?

Comment: Por enquanto, pelo Swagger mesmo, inserindo o id, e o format.

Comment: E também não entendi, por que o filtro se você tem uma rota exclusiva para retornar o xml

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, são tentativas para fazer funcionar, nenhuma deu certo. srsrsrsr Consegui fazer funcionar com o core 3.0. mas, com esse ainda não.

Comment: Então eu tenho um exemplo com a versão mais recente a v5 e funciona perfeitamente não precisa escrever nada na classe é só confiugrar e utilizar e o mesmo imprime xml ou json

Comment: Verifiquei minha classe.

E alguns `System.Xml.Serialization` não estavam funcionando. Por isso o erro 406.

Foi necessário refazer eles. (foram gerados automáticos pelo Visual Studio a partir de um arquivo .xml)